# Extract value of cell from each column, where row value matches value in vector

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, vector

I have a vector of years (97).
I also have a data frame with "year" and 97 columns of values.

| Year | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 5.663 |
| 2021 | 9.344 |

vector (97): 2050, 2045, 2047 ......

For column 1 I need to extract the value of the first year of the vector, 2050, for column 2 the second value of the vector, 2045, etc..

[image: dataframe]

I'm not sure how to do this, I thought maybe a loop would be best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood; is this your expected output?

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022),
                 Col1 = rnorm(3),
                 Col2 = rnorm(3),
                 Col3 = rnorm(3))
df
#>   Year       Col1       Col2       Col3
#> 1 2020 -0.5604756 0.07050839  0.4609162
#> 2 2021 -0.2301775 0.12928774 -1.2650612
#> 3 2022  1.5587083 1.71506499 -0.6868529

years_vec <- c(2022, 2021)

output <- list()
for (i in seq_along(years_vec)) {
  output[[i]] <- df[match(years_vec[i], df$Year), i + 1]
}
unlist(output)
#> [1] 1.5587083 0.1292877
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Let's create some data

```
data <- data.frame(Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023),
                    `1` = c(5.663, 9.344, 1.2, 2.3),
                    `2` = c(7.123, 8.234, 3.2, 4.3),
                    `3` = c(6.789, 7.890, 5.2, 6.3))
vec <- c(2021, 2022, 2023)
```

Now we need to match the years in data frame with your vector, then find the column indices, subset, convert to matrix and grab the diagonal,

```
i1 <- match(vec, data$Year)
i2 <- 1:length(vec)

diag(as.matrix(data[i1, i2 + 1]))
# [1] 9.344 3.200 6.300
```